# Writing a super simple LED code, having issues with not being able to import from gpiozero

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, led

Im trying to use my raspberry pi electronics kit to run an LED program. My code is just:

```
from gpiozero import led
from signal import pause

led = LED(4)

led.blink()

pause()
```

Which throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python-projects/led.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gpiozero import led
ImportError: cannot import name 'led' from 'gpiozero' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/__init__.py)
>>>
```

I have tried reinstalling throught apt with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3-gpiozero python-gpiozero` but nothing has changed. Im sure its something stupidly simple, I just dont know enough yet to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), it should be `LED`, not `led`:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

led = LED(17)

while True:
    led.on()
    sleep(1)
    led.off()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Knew it was something that dumb, thank you so much